# Does Dreamweaver 8 support SVN integration?

Tags: svn, dreamweaver

I am new to Dreamweaver and using version 8. Does it support SVN integration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not. The first version of Dreamweaver to integrate Subversion natively is CS4. I believe there might have been a third party Subversion extension available to earlier versions, but it isn't part of the core application.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Dreamweaver very little. However, I do find that using third party tools are best for dealing with a program's tasks that are outside its main focus.

For example:

- SVN: Use [TortioseSVN or command line](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- FTP: Use [WinSCP](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwinscp.net%2F&ei=77H5SpTlNI7WngeVtoCHDQ&usg=AFQjCNGEJFUGYT96lPqbeHy5liKeOV1P3w&sig2=Ps1sRxwR1bsm8zxA9iit6A)/[OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) (SFTP) or [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)

Typically the third party tools are better and more efficient at performing the task than those built into the IDEs.

To me its a bit like going to a convenience store to buy groceries. You can do it but its not as efficent and its not the main purpose of the store to do so.

Additionally, learning how to use the tool outside the context of the problem will mean that you can apply and reuse the new knowledge to tasks unrelated to DreamWeaver. In summary: you are doing yourself a huge disservice for the sake of a small convenience.

Comment: It might not be as good at groceries, but it's a lot more convenient.

Comment: Adding to my analogy, you can buy crisps/chips there but don't expect to get Mangos or Watermelons.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can do it with third party extensions - see [this article](http://strivinglife.com/words/post/Installing-Subversion-and-TortoiseSVN-to-a-Windows-XP-Home-Edition-SP2-local-machine-with-Dreamweaver-8.aspx) for step-by-step instructions.